# Python downloading hyperlink with urllib2

Tags: python, web-scraping, raspberry-pi, urllib2

Still new with urllib2 so sorry if this is a basic question but I couldn't find an answer anywhere that made sense. Tried to make a basic web scraper on the raspberry pi with python 2.7.9 that finds a url in the site and downloads the file however I keep getting http 503 errors even if I loop over and retry it never goes through.

```
    import cfscrape
    import urllib2

    def find_hyperlink( text, first, last):
        try:
            start = text.index(first) + len (first)
            end = text.index (last, start)
            return text[start:end]
        except ValueError:
            return ""

    def download_hyperlink(name):
        scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()
        r= scraper.get(name).content
        link = find_hyperlink(r, 'Download (Save as...): <a href="', '">')
        print link
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
        try:
            response = opener.open(link)
            print 'downloading episode'
        except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
            if e.code == 503:
                download_hyperlink(name)
            else:
                 raise

    download_hyperlink('http://www.kiss-anime.me/Anime-sword-art-online-episode-1')
```

Comment: Getting error 503 is not your fault: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html
When I checked the website, I got a DDos protection page. Probably that is also the reason why you get a 503

Comment: Try using this site instead. http://animehaven.to/dubbed/sword-art-online-episode-1

Comment: The site is protected by cloudfare so exactly as you see in your browser you have to wait 5 seconds the first time you access the site which urllib wont do